# how to fetch data in JPA that can have null value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination

i am trying to filter data from the table that have null value. 
i am trying to fetch data by searching two fields where name is not nullable field and productGroup.name is a nullable field.
this is my code:

```
    public static Page page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    Long total = (Long) JPA.em()
            .createQuery("select count(c) from InventoryItem c where  lower(c.name) like :filter or c.productGroup.name=:filter ")
            .setParameter("filter", "%" + filter.toLowerCase() + "%")
            .getSingleResult();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<InventoryItem> data = JPA.em()
            .createQuery("from InventoryItem c where lower(c.name) like :filter or c.productGroup.name=:filter order by c." + sortBy + " " + order)
            .setParameter("filter", "%" + filter.toLowerCase() + "%")
            .setFirstResult((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .setMaxResults(pageSize)
            .getResultList();
    return new Page(data, total, page, pageSize);
}
```

if there is null value in productGroup.name it does not fetch the data but when i store productGroup.name it shows the data. Am i doing any wrong??

Thanks

Comment: so look at the SQL invoked and then you can see why that happens ...

Answer (score 1):

if you like to select the rows where the name is like the filter or null you have to change it to:

... or (c.productGroup.name=:filter  OR c.productGroup.name is null)

You can't set the filter to null and expect that the rows where the name is null will be returned....

Comment: i already tried this but this does not fetch any data..  list appear to be empty even there's item.

Comment: But this is the correct way. Please post the query you tried ... Or check the sql which is generated in the log

Comment: `        List<InventoryItem> data = JPA.em()
                .createQuery("from InventoryItem c where lower(c.name) like :filter or (c.productGroup.name=:filter OR c.productGroup.name is null) order by c." + sortBy + " " + order)
                .setParameter("filter", "%" + filter.toLowerCase() + "%")
                .setFirstResult((page - 1) * pageSize)
                .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                .getResultList(); 

        System.out.println("size: "+data.size());`

Comment: its shows data that have product group but i  still cant fetch data that dont have product group

Comment: Ok .. the row where the name is null, is there the c.name null, too? Then you have to change it to: ( lower(c.name) like :filter or c.productGroup.name=:filter OR c.productGroup.name is null). You should log the generated sql and execute this sql direct to the database.... or try it first with a simple version of your query: "from InventoryItem c where c.productGroup.name is null". if this works you can add a additional "or" clause ...

Comment: Is only the name of productGroup null, or is the "whole"  productGroup null?

Comment: c.name is not null field and has data. only c.productGroup.name is nullable.  it still shows the same result.  data with productGroup.name is not fetching . it fetches the data that have both value

Comment: Is only the name of productGroup null, or is there no productGroup?

Comment: this is no product group

Comment: THIS is the problem :-) .. the query ..c.productGroup.name ... will result in an sql like 'select * from inventoryItem INNER JOIN productGroup where name is null' but if there is no productGroup this will fail ... you have to write something like "from InventoryItem c LEFT JOIN c.productGroup where lower(c.name) like :filter or (c.productGroup.name=:filter OR c.productGroup.name is null)'

Comment: Now i have a casting problem. How do i cast whole list directly to InventoryItem class?

Comment: thank you @Si mo its working but now it dont filter for the c.name field. it shows all the time even i send the invalid name and works perfectly for c.ProductGroup.name

Comment: Your concatentation is alway "OR" in the query. If you filter now you get everything where productGroupName is null OR c.name like ...I think you have to change it to "AND" .." where lower(c.name) like :filter AND (c.productGroup.name= ...)

Comment: thank you @si mo, this code works perfect:
                  






















































**`.createQuery("select c from InventoryItem c LEFT JOIN  c.productGroup where lower(c.name) like :filter or c.productGroup.name like :filter and (c.productGroup.name like :filter OR c.productGroup.name is null) order by c." + sortBy + " " + order)`**